# Adding data to SCNNode and archiving

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit

I am weighing my options to add custom data to `SCNNode` instances.

One way I have been thinking of is using associated objects.

The other is to use an `SCNNode` subclass.

Concerning associated objects, I am wondering about the possibility to archive the scene with `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(_:toFile:)` and retain data.

Concerning an `SCNNode` subclass, that would mean my scene graph would be made of that subclass instances as opposed to `SCNNode` instances. I was wondering if that could cause trouble.

I have made a request to Apple in the bug reports to add a `userData` property to `SCNNode` similar to that of `SKNode` in `SpriteKit`, but in the meantime, I need to find a way with what we got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like `CALayer`, `SCNNode` is a [key-value coding compliant container class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW3) and allows you to use KVC for arbitrary keys. `SCNNode` conforms to the `NSSecureCoding` protocol and will automatically archive these additional keys.

Comment: I think I will use that technique. I have started implementing it for my level editor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A downside to subclassing is that you won't be able to use the Xcode Scene Editor with your scene graph. That might not matter to you.

If you're not using it for anything else, the `name` property might help you. You could store a unique key there, and use it to index the custom data.

Comment: Interesting idea as well.